# Differentiate request from admin portal and from basic API - Django/REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was wondering if it was possible to differentiate a request from the Django administration portal from a request from the API ?

For example, using permissions, a user would not be able to delete an instance with a basic API call. But the same user through the admin portal would be able to delete the instance.

I tried to look at the parameters of the request object but didn't find anything that can be used.

---

In my ideal case: User A can delete objects through the admin dashboard but the same User A cannot delete objects when not using the admin dashboard.

Comment: Admin dashboard already provides functionality of delete according to permissions set for user. Also, If you want to develop an API then rather than checking the source, check for user if she/ he has permission to delete that object.

Comment: Hi! I've set the permissions based on the user's group. But what I would like to do is : Allow User A to delete objects when using the admin dashboard while forbid the same User A to delete objects when not using the admin dashboard. I'm not sure if I'm understandable.. I've been asked to implement this but I find it weird

Comment: In that case you can check request.path attribute when deleting via admin in case it contains something to figure out. And if that also doesn't work than override admin template and  add some information in context whenever someone is deletig via admin. And yes, its weird. They want to test your skills I suppose :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try to see if I can figure out something. If it's not working I'll modify the admin dashboard like you suggest.